# strip_tags + html entities to get only numbers

Tags: php, regex

I would like to remove everything but the amount as a float from this string:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8362;</span>700.00</span>
```

I tried:

1. `strip_tags( $total_price_paid );` - Not enough.
2. `strip_tags( html_entity_decode( $total_price_paid ) );` - it decodes the entity into a symbol, i tried preg_replace after and it didn't work.
3. `preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $value );` - Doesn't get rid of html entity

None of those achieved a result of `700.00` formatted as a float.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove also the special pieces of text used to define *entities*, so you need at least another pass:

```
$total_price_paid = strip_tags($total_price_paid);
$total_price_paid = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i", "", $total_price_paid);
```

Code snippet is available [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/909a328b1241b30a96c3a4586d6b7b8ac3d66b82).

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span>700.00</span>';

echo floatval(substr($str, stripos($str, "</span>")+7, strripos($str, "</span>")+7));
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors and I don't get the result that I wanted.
Thank you anyway, I have accepted Alex's answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry I have editted the content again. you may check it if you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use preg_match then you can use like that:

```
$string = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8362;</span>700.00</span>';

preg_match('/\d+\.\d{1,2}/', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[0]; // 700.00
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/087253390b98f9350c20ae2a63774784136b5abe)